# Connect-MgGraph in Azure Automation

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I am currently busy to convert my Azure AD PowerShell scripts to Microsoft Graph PowerShell. I have already some scripts that I want to run within Azure Automation, but I try to figure out how to connect to Azure Automation.

With Azure AD PowerShell, I have a connected service account in Azure Automation. With Microsoft Graph PowerShell I'm trying to use a RunAs account within the Azure Automation Account with the following connection:

```
$Connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
# Get certificate from the automation account
$Certificate = Get-AutomationCertificate -Name AzureRunAsCertificate
# Connect to the Graph SDK endpoint using the automation account
Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $Connection.ApplicationId -TenantId $Connection.TenantId -CertificateThumbprint $Connection.CertificateThumbprint
```

When I run the RunBook to create the connection I get an error:

```
Connect-MgGraph: C:\Temp\os4k24vd.4cs\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ps1:5
Line | 5 | Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $Connection.ApplicationId -TenantId $Connec …
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0,
| Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxx'. The system cannot | find the file specified.
```

I have the following module installed that is needed for `Connect-MgGraph` **Microsoft.Graph.Authentication** >> Runtime: **7.1** When I search on the error, it have something to do that .NET could not find the Json.NET library. But which module I'm missing in Azure Automation, or are there other ways to connect Microsoft Graph PowerShell with Azure Automation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the first connect script, but the runtime version. After changing to PS 5.1 instead of 7.1 it all works. The Runbook now shows 'Welcome to Welcome To Microsoft Graph!'

```
$Connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection

# Connect to the Graph SDK endpoint using the automation account
Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $Connection.ApplicationId -TenantId $Connection.TenantId -CertificateThumbprint $Connection.CertificateThumbprint
```

Comment: ``AzureRunAsConnections`` are announced to be deprected in Sep 2023 and should not longer beeing used.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using **App only Access** approach to connect the Azure Automation. if not refer [MSDOC - App only Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/app-only?view=graph-powershell-1.0&tabs=powershell)

To get the **Certificate** and **AppID** you can use the below command let

```
#To get App Id
$AppId = Get-AutomationVariable -Name '<Your AppID>'

# Get TenentId
$TenantId = Get-AutomationVariable -Name '< your tenantId>'

# Get Certificate
$CertificateName = Get-AutomationCertificate -Name '<Your Certificate>'

#Connect the mgGraph 
Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $AppId -TenantId $TenantId -CertificateName $CertificateName ## Or -CertificateThumbprint
```

Still, you are facing issue please give a try [Automation Hybrid Runbook Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker) for more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, will check your detailed answer. Will comeback on it.

Comment: I have come a step further, with above connect script in Azure Automation, but now I get another strange message.

`Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $AppId -TenantId $TenantId -CertificateName …
[Serial Number] XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [Not Before]
8/1/2022 12:00:00 AM [Not After] 8/2/2023 12:00:00 AM [Thumbprint] 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX certificate was not found or has expired`

This is strange because the certificate expired on 8/2/2023 and when I go to the certificate tab in Azure Automation the cert is listed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uzing `AzContext` this solution might work for you! Define `AzurePowerShell@5` specifying AzureSubscription in it, get a graph token for MS Graph and set that to `Connect-MgGraph`.

This is my pipeline:

```yaml
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Update App Registration'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: 'scripts/the_script_name.ps1'
    pwsh: true
```

And this is my `the_script_name.ps1`:

```
$context = Get-AzContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$securegt = ConvertTo-SecureString $graphToken -AsPlainText -Force

Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $securegt
```